# How to migrate a git project from using master as the default branch to main?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm the maintainer of a project that's hosted on github/gitlab which has a number of contributors. I want to migrate from using `master` as the default branch to `main`. How do I do that without messing up?

I've read some blog-posts on the topic, but would prefer a discussion over here at StackOverflow where comments might point out issues that a single person could have overlooked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Github offers a migration option, so it's trivial. But even with any other service like gitlab that doesn't have something like that (yet), as long as you're doing the right steps it's relatively straight-forward, at least from a technical point of view.

Either way, unless your project is quite small, the biggest hassle will surely be getting all your contributors to apply fixes to work-in-progress correctly.

### What you need to do

**Github**

On your project page, navigate to `settings`, and in the section "Default branch", press the edit button and change it from `master` to `main`.

**Gitlab, aka migrating manually**

I'm assuming that your remote/upstream is called `origin` - if it's called something different, replace `origin` with that name in all commands accordingly.

1. Rename the most recent `master` to `main`, and push it upstream:

```bash
git fetch origin
git branch --move master main
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

2. Tell your upstream that `main` is the new default:

   - Navigate to `settings/repository`, section "Default branch", select `main` and press "Save Changes". Then, on the same page, go the the section "Protected branches", and protect `main` and unprotect `master`, and press "Save Changes".
3. Delete `master` on upstream - not strictly necessary, but does reduce confusion:

```bash
git push origin --delete master
```

4. Migrate open merge/pull requests that wanted to be pushed into `master` to be pushed into `main` instead:

   - On an open merge request, press "edit". On the top, it should say "From <branch_name> into `master`". Change the drop-down from `master` to `main`.

### What your collaborators/colleagues need to do

```bash
git fetch origin --prune && git branch -m master main && git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
```

As far as I know, that's it - the `&&`s are a good idea to protect you in case something doesn't add up.

---

Please leave a comment if you ran into issues following this advice. `git` fuckups are hellish to untangle, so the least we can do is to try and not reinvent [the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wheel) any more than we need to.

Comment: Please do not suggest to delete a branch in the local repository because it erases the reflog. Better only rename the branch: `git checkout master; git branch -m main; git branch --set-upstream-to origin/main`.

Comment: @j6t You're referring to the script below the `What your collaborators/colleagues need to do` section, right? I'd assumed it only deletes a name, given that the newly checked out `main` holds the complete history that used to be on `master`. Anyway, if your version is just a safer way to reach the same goal, then I'll happily use yours. Can you confirm that for me?

Comment: Yes, the script for collaborators. But no, deleting a branch not only affects the name, but also the reflog, i.e. all the states that the branch was in, whether they are in the branch's current history or not. When it's wiped out, recovery of states that are not in the history becomes difficult. That may or may not be a problem.

Comment: I'd suggest that collaborators run `git fetch origin --prune && git branch -m master main && git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main`. This should work regardless of which branch they are on; if they have no branch named `master`, the second command will fail and the third one won't run, but they'll be fine.

Comment: Alright, no local delete then, just rename. That's exactly the kind of advice I was looking for, thanks. @torek, can I get an explanation what the `--prune` does, will it get rid of `origin/master`, or just a good idea in general?

Comment: The `--prune` flag tells your Git software: *After you've connected to the remote Git repo and gotten a list of all of their branch names, *remove* from *my* repo any remote-tracking name that no longer has a branch name on their end.* So this will auto-delete your `origin/master`. In fact, I like this prune mode enough to run `git config --global fetch.prune true`, which makes it the default. It does have a few sharp edges though: a fetch with a weird refspec can wind up pruning a bunch of names inappropriately.

Comment: Most people will never hit the sharp edges except if they use a single-branch clone (and then they might actually *like* that edge, a paring knife or scalpel to cut out the stuff you don't want, as it were).

Answer (score 0):

I'm managing a self-hosted gitlab instance (v13.x.y), and you don't have to do it manually - there's a similar solution to this as the one mentioned by Arne for github.

First, copy your master branch to main branch.
Then, go to project `Settings`, click `Repository`, and change the default branch.

[image]
[image]

After that, you can use the above snippet to update your local repository (change the branch names if you need to), or if you're worried that you might mess something up, you can delete the project and clone it again.